# How to bind the value of disabled input in reactive form Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I can't bind one of my inputs from a FormGroup:

```html
<input matInput placeholder="Center" value="Manila" formControlName="location" disabled>
```

It is also not disabled.

When I insert `[(ngModel)]="location"` so I can get the value, it is said to be removed or deprecated. The input is disabled though.

**My form (snippet):**

```html
<mat-form-field class="tribe-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Tribe Name" value="" formControlName="tribeName">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="tribe-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Tribe Leader Name" value="" formControlName="tribeLeader">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="tribe-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Center" value="Manila" formControlName="location">
</mat-form-field>
```

**My component:**

```js
onSubmitTribeData() {
  console.log(this.tribeForm.value);
}

addTribe(){
  if (this.showForm === false) {
    this.showForm = true;
    this.tribeForm.controls['dtcLocation'].disable(); 
    this.tribeForm = this.fb.group({
      tribeName: [''],
      tribeLeader: [''],
      location: [''],
      tribeSquad: ['']
    });
  } else {
    this.showForm = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you demonstrate the problem in a stackblitz snippet ?

Comment: to show the values use myForm.getRawValue(), not myForm.value: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue, to give a value use myForm.get('location').setValue(), and NEVER use together [ngModel] and formControlName on a variable that belongs to the formGroup

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have setup your reactive-form like this:

```js
export class YourComponent {
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    location: new FormControl(''),
  });

  constructor() {}

  someFunction(): any {
    // You can access the value of an input as follows:
    const value = this.myForm.get('location').value;
  }
}
```

You can disable the input in your template via `[attr.disabled]`:

```html
<input matInput [attr.disabled]="true" placeholder="Center" value="DTC Manila" formControlName="location">
```

Or you can do so programmatically in your component:

```js
this.myForm.controls['location'].disable(); 
this.myForm.controls['location'].enable(); // To re-enable the input.
```

Note: `[(ngModel)]` should not be used with reactive-forms as [support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and was removed in Angular v7.](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel)

Comment: If `location` is always disabled, you could initialize it like: `location: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true})`.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post. Please check it. Also I used [attr.disabled]="true" and this.myForm.controls['location'].disable(); but it didn't work

Comment: @Mark - The steps outlined in this answer are how you current disable inputs in Angular reactive forms. For us to help any further you would need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
this.formGroup.controls['controlName'].setValue(value);
```

Please avoid using `disabled` attribute with reactive forms. Either you can initialise the control with;

```
new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true})
```

or use this where you want to disable the control;

```
this.formGroup.controls['controlName'].disable();
```